# How to install skype in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: skype, software-installation

I have trouble installing skype in Ubuntu 13.10. Installing skype through the Software Center gives an error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and after removing skype by using `sudo apt-get remove skype` I tried to install skype with

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

which gives an error

```
E: Package 'skype:i386' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas how I can install skype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the deb file for ubuntu 12.04  from this link

[Download Skype on your computer - Windows, Mac, and Linux - Get Skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)

Then issue dpkg command to install

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

you may miss some dependencies so issue this command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check whether Canonical Partners is ticked in Software Sources. If no, check it and update.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and do as I mention

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

thats it, It will install skype in your Ubuntu.

don't worry about bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Install with:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
wget -O skype-install.deb https://get.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

If you get an error:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
```

Comment: Follow the code in that order to be able to install

Comment: @Alex this will solve your errors.